# remove meta analysis from forest plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, meta, r-forestplot

I'm using the `meta` R package to create a forest plot:

```
library(meta)    
m1 <- metacont(10 + 1:4, 1:4, c(1:2, 3, 4),
                   10 + 1:4, 1:4, c(1:2, 3, 4))
    
forest(m1)
```

[image]

I now want to remove the meta analysis and weights and the squares should also be of equal size. It should visualize the effects only.
I photoshopped this:

[image]

How can I achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove those values with `overall`.

```
forest.meta(m1,overall=FALSE, overall.hetstat = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can check all possibility at the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/meta/versions/4.15-1/topics/forest.meta)